# Please explain why PHP switch case is always executing case 0 in this code

Tags: php, switch-statement

Can someone please explain why the case "a" is never reached in below code and why it will always execute case 0

```
switch ("a") {
case 0:
    echo "0";
    break;
case "a": // never reached because "a" is already matched with 0
    echo "a";
    break;
}
```

Comment: switch cannot be used on string and numbers at same time [read more](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php#82351)

Comment: Just a guess, but the fact that some of the switch values are ints and some are strings may be causing a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP, like JavaScript or Perl, is a loosely-typed language and will attempt to guess what you want to do. In this case, it changed your string to the closest integer it could find, which is zero. In other words, `"a" == 0` is a true statement in PHP.

More on this topic can be found in the PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). I suggest you typecast the value in the `switch` statement, or replace it with an `if`/`elseif`/`else` construct.

---

As of PHP 8.0, [this behaviour has changed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/string_to_number_comparison) and now the integer value will always be changed to a string before comparison between the two types. Strictly typing and comparing your variables remains the recommended practice, however.

Comment: I linked the wrong example... https://3v4l.org/tC3pt. That's not so predictable from what I can tell.

Comment: Interesting, it seems like sometimes it's the value in `select` that gets juggled and sometimes it's the value in `case`.

Comment: Yeah it's very strange. Try making the value of `$x = "0";`...   I can see how it would be false, but at the same time it's a literal value of "0" and still favors "false" over it's real case. I think it has to do with the ordering in some ways perhaps, but I can't be certain.

Comment: Putting in `$x = "false";` skips right over false and hit's the default case. The treatment of quotes around the values or switches plays a role too obviously.

Answer (score 2):

You can not used mix-cases in a switch statement as PHP will interpret the meaning of what you mean.

In layman's terms, it will try to find the 'value of "a"' which is not defined to the processor, and hence is 0 in this case.

Same will go for the code below:

```
<?php

$x = "a";
switch($x)
{
    case "c":
        echo "c";
    break;

    case 1:
        echo "1";
    break;  

    case 0:
        echo "0";
    break;

    case "a":
        echo "a";
    break;

    case false:
        echo "false";
    break;

    default:
        echo "def";
    break;
}

?>
```

[Documentation is available at PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is because `switch` uses a [loose comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose) `==`

That said:

```
if ("a" == 0) // TRUE
if ("a" == true) // TRUE
```

Pretty much anything else will evaluate to false. (except `"a" == "a"`)

So, if you have the need to compare against both strings and integers, you should just convert to string for the comparison.

```
//$var = "a";
$var = 0;

$var = strval($var);
switch ($var) {
    case '0':
        echo "0";
        break;
    case 'a':
        echo "a";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable type used on case() should be same type used in switch().

```
   <?php
    switch ("a") {
       case "0":
          echo "0";
          break;
       case "a": // never reached because "a" is already matched with 0
          echo "a";
          break;
    }
```

For integer type:

```
<?php
switch (1) {
  case 0:
    echo 0;
    break;
  case 1: // never reached because "a" is already matched with 0
    echo 1;
    break;
}
```